# If I update to Mavericks, will I be able to boot from USB?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, macos

running a late 2009 (5,5) Macbook Pro. I am currently unable to boot from liveUSB disks, but would really like to. I know that newer macs can do this (Macbook Air, new MBPs), but is it a hardware or a software thing? If I update to Mavericks, would I be able to do this on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the operating system. The update will not change your ability or inability to boot in any particular way.

The stage of the boot process you're talking about is handled by the firmware, not by the operating system.

Comment: This might be an answer, but it isn't clear what you mean. Please edit your answer to explain better.

Comment: Do you know if there's a firmware update that might change this, or am I forever stuck in the land of non-usb-booting?

Comment: @kennethsime: Well of course you can boot over USB, but it must be an EFI-aware system. OS X for one, and some brand-new Linux distro releases are EFI-aware IIRC.

Comment: I will have to look into this more, that is my goal; booting linux from usb.